# C++ no match for 'operator>>' in 'std::cin

Tags: c++, operators, cin

In my struct I have a functon, in this I want to read the line, these are integers.

Here is a part of the Code (C++):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

struct kunde
    {
      [..]
    }
struct kmph_in_mps
        {
            int kmph[4];
            double result[10];

            void kmph_erfassen() //In english: kmph_read
            {
                cout << "TEST";
                cin >> kmph;
            }
```

I want to read km/h from console.
But I just get: error: no match for 'operator>>' in 'std::cin >> kmph'|

Comment: `kmph` is an array. You need to read into one of the 4 elements of the array.

Comment: Well, there is no overload for `int(&)[4]` or `int*`. What should such an overload do anyway? If you decide on that, you can add it though. Also, fixed your tags.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to write to each index of the `kmph` array, such as

```
void kmph_erfassen() //In english: kmph_read
{
    cout << "TEST";
    for (size_t i = 0; i < 4; ++i)
    {
        cin >> kmph[i];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

By default, you can do:

```
cin >> single_int;
```

but there's no operator to do

```
cin >> array_of_ints;
```

You have to do it in a loop:

```
for (int& k : kmph) {
    cin >> k;
}
```

or non-C++11:

```
for (int i = 0; i < sizeof(kmph)/sizeof(*kmph); ++i) {
    cin >> kmph[i];
}
```

Comment: @Sinmson I do not understand what you are asking.

Comment: Before I tryed to use it in the function, I used this in my main class, and there this worked without compiling problems.

Comment: I'm guessing you weren't trying to cin into an array when you did it in main?

Comment: There is no way that is true. This program: `int main() { int k[4]; std::cin >> k; }` cannot compile.

Comment: Then open another question with that code and ask why it works. I am sure you did something different than you think you did, but we can't read your mind.

Answer (score 0):

Your array `kmph` is an array, and you want to read each character at a time:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
{
    cin >> kmph[i];
}
```